# How to make locally running java-servlet endpoint as subscriber to Topic of Amazon SNS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, notifications, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I am trying to subscribe Java-servlet running locally in tomacat server and 
I tried following things to subscribe it:

1) I wrote small hello-world-servlet code and printing "Hello-World" in console if I get request from Amazon SNS.

2) I did port forwarding to my router, so that my servlet could be accessible through Internet.

3) My public https link is looking like this: `"https://router-ip-address:8483/SNSSub/TestSubscription"`
TestSubscription is a servlet url and SNSSub is a webapps name.

AWS allows to add public https-link as subscriber to topic and print message which says, request is pending. But I do not receive subscription request to my servlet.

Does Amazon SNS not send subscription request to https endpoint that have not a signed certificate from a trusted CA? Look this link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.https.ca.html .
So, locally running http endpoint need signed certificate to receive even first subscription request from Amazon SNS

Comment: Dear Chandra can you please post the servlet code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am successfully able to make call after adding keystore of signed certificate to my localhost.

HTTPS Endpoint of Amazon SNS requires signed certificate to be store in your machine even if it is first call of subscription.

HTTP request does not require any kind of certificate.